# Adaptar código para retornar a posição do mouse

Tags: c++, opencv, eventos-do-mouse

Estou com o seguinte código que me mostra os valores das coordenadas X e Y quando clico duas vezes com o botão esquerdo do mouse.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void mouse_callback(int  event, int  x, int  y, int  flag, void *param)
{
    if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
    {
        cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("img1.jpg");

    namedWindow("exemplo");
    setMouseCallback("exemplo", mouse_callback);

    imshow("exemplo", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Porém, preciso retornar as coordenadas x e y para realizar alguns cálculos e não estou conseguindo.

Alguém sabe como adaptar o código? Tentei trocar o tipo da função para `int` e passar x e y por referência, mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Você não pode alterar a assinatura do callback. Se quer fazer cálculos fora dela, armazene os valores em variáveis globais, ou chame a sua própria callback a partir dela.

Comment: Consegui fazer o que eu queria usando variáveis globais. Muito obrigado!